# Teaching a foreign language resources - The Direct Approach (or Method)

Tags: resource-request, electronic-resources, teaching, italian

Two friends have told me they want to learn to speak Italian and are interested in paying me to teach them. I have an illness that makes it hard for me to work so I need to find a way to earn some money so this could be really helpful. I studied Italian intensively in Florence under the Direct Approach (or Method) and can now talk Italian without thinking (much). I have also studied drama, lived in Italy, and trained to be a ski instructor, so with the tools from each of these, I feel that I could actually do this and I am hoping to be able to do it using the Direct Approach (or Method).

However, I am in need of free resources to use in these classes, e.g. ideas for games, lesson plans, techniques, pictures of objects, etc.

Is there somewhere I can look online to download free language teaching resources?

Comment: Welcome to Language Learning Stack Exchange! This is an interesting first question. Are your friends absolute beginners? Do they speak another Romance language (e.g. French or Spanish) or only totally unrelated languages?

Comment: They have a second home in Italy so have absorbed a few phrases (incorrectly for the most part) but that's it from what I can tell so far.

Comment: I don't know if they speak any other languages. I need to probe further.

Comment: OP: You should also take a look at italki.com website, a portal connecting students and teachers of various languages, so you can check the going price for such lessons, and find more paying customers.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a list of websites with Italian language teaching resources:

- [The Italian Teaching Resources Website](https://www.teachitalian.co.uk/), a collaborative effort of Italian language teachers in the UK.
- [Italian Teaching Resources](https://www.languagecoursesuk.co.uk/online-teaching-resources/italian-online-teaching-resources/) by Cactus Worldwide Ltd. (UK).
- BBC: [resources for the BBC Active Italian course](http://www.bbcactivelanguages.com/TeachersHome/ResourcesItalian/tabid/98/Default.aspx).
- ILUSS (Florence, Italy): [ree Italian Language Learning Resources](http://www.iluss.it/schede_gram_free.html) (part of the resources appear to require registration).
- Bright Hub Education: [Italian Lesson Plans for Secondary Grades 6–12](http://www.brighthubeducation.com/italian-lesson-plans/).
- AQA: [Teaching and learning resources](http://www.aqa.org.uk/subjects/languages/gcse/italian-4630/teaching-and-learning-resources).

Answer (score 1):

Another interesting site where you can find some resources (basically exercises on different aspects of Italian language) is [Adgblog](https://www.adgblog.it/) from Accademia del Giglio in Florence. For instance, [here](https://www.adgblog.it/2011/12/22/100-songs-to-learn-italian/) you will find some materials to learn Italian with songs classified at 3 levels according to the European common framework of reference of language learning and teaching, with exercises and with indications of the subject which they focus on (tenses, prepositions, vocabulary, etc.).

Answer (score -1):

Once you’ve learned to speak a few [Italian phrases](https://www.rosettastone.com/italian-phrases) and practiced your pronunciation, you’ll be able to build upon what you’ve learned to become comfortable having conversations in Italian. The goal of a language learning program isn’t just about cramming you full of Italian vocabulary. It should also be about encouraging your confidence as an Italian speaker so when you do have conversations in real-world settings, you’ll be able to understand, speak, and be understood.

[Rosetta Stone](https://www.rosettastone.com) has a language learning program that scales carefully towards speaking Italian like a local, with immersive, practical exercises built around the following language learning strategies.

Comment: 1. Are you affiliated with Rosetta stone? It is fine, but you need to mention it explicitly. 2. How can a teacher benefit from using the website as a source of exercises?